# What level of complexity can a custom ConfigSection XML contain while using built-in Section Handler classes?

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

This example on MSDN shows how to implement a simple dictionary inside a custom App.config section:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719887(v=vs.71).aspx

The XML looks like this, and it employs `SingleTagSectionHandler`:

```
<sampleSection setting1="Value1" setting2="value two" 
               setting3="third value" />
```

Is this the most complicated my custom XML section can be before I have to write my own config section class? Because I wish to have a section which is slightly more complex e.g:

```
<mySection>
    <mappings>
        <mapping name="A" val1="12" val2="32"/>
        <mapping name="B" val1="2" val2="2"/>
    </mappings>
    <add name="URL" value="http://..."/>
</mySection>
```

Or something along those lines at least, the exact structure isn't rigid.

How far can I push the built-in section handlers? I couldn't see a good tutorial on what is actually provided in `system.configuration`.

Comment: It's definitely possible. I don't like standard configuration file, but if you have decided to go with it - have a look at [Configuration Section Designer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/756a0b92-7e60-4df3-93d7-7eea94e4017a?SRC=VSIDE). It's free, generates classes and xsd files to validate your custom section.

Comment: @JurySoldatenkov that's interesting thanks, but not strictly what I'm asking for (which I guess is fine since it's a comment)